# Is the Toolbar able to work in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm new in Android Programming. I would like to ask that does `Toolbar` able to work in `RelativeLayout`? So far I manage to create them using `LinearLayout`. Would like to hear some guidance form you all. Thanks.

The question is: how do I prevent the content from overlaying on top of the `Toolbar` content?

Comment: I don't see how it wont work.

Comment: It does not work on old versions of Android, unless layout:below is specified on the view below the toolbar, it overlaps.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, we can add toolbar within Relative layout .

But you need to mention layout:below attribute since it will overlap.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#ffbb00">


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it's better just add toolbar to end (so it would on top), for example if you make a video player you would like transparent toolbar over video